# Decrypt aggregate signature scheme

Tags: encryption, bls-signature, multi-signature

I've learnt in the university course that using BLS, one can generate an aggregate signature using public keys of a given parties. We can then use a given party's public key to verify his participation in the aggregated signature.

But... does BLS or any other scheme allow us to encrypt a message with the aggregated signature of public keys $A,B,C$ for example and then decrypt the message with the private key of one of the parties?

Comment: You may be interested in [group encryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/015.pdf).

Comment: "does BLS ... allow us to encrypt a message ... with the ... public key... and then decrypt the message with the private key"?"; no, BLS does not do public key encryption (even with a single key, much less aggregated keys...)